# Why is Capistrano deploying my project in "development" environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, production-environment

I have the following files set up for my capistrano configuration. When I deploy my project with the following command it deploys to the server, but the `Rails.env` is set to 'deployment'.  How can I have it properly set to 'production'?

**deploy command**

```
cap production deploy
```

**deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'project'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:AccountName/project.git'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/project'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

**config/deploy/production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production
set :branch, 'master'
set :rails_env, 'production'

server '127.0.0.1:4400', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip_address;
    rails_env production;
    root /path/to/app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

**sites-available/project**

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name ip_address;
   passenger_enabled on;
   root /path/to/app/public;
}
```

Comment: How is your app being run (passenger, unicorn etc) ?

Comment: nginx & passenger I followed the following article once upon a time to setup... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: So found the problem after you mentioned that.. there is a setting in nginx that's the following: `passenger_app_env development` ... Edit: Well I thought it fixed it however it still says its in development. I'm checking on restarting but i think my deploy command already restarts it...

Comment: Your deploy isn't restarting nginx itself

Comment: I added `service nginx restart` to my task restart.  I also signed on to the server and ran it there. Still getting development environment.  Is there another location where the passenger_app_env is still set to development other than sites-available?

Comment: you can specify [rails_env in the nginx configuration](http://ershadk.com/blog/2012/04/05/set-up-rails-3-2-2-with-passenger-rvm-and-ngnix/). Also I restart on web like so `namespace :deploy do
  task :restart, :roles => :web do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end`

Comment: @engineersmnky, I believe I already have that in place in my `deploy.rb` no?  It seems to be restarting but im not sure. that restart.txt file exists in that location.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I restarted nginx, also posted what my nginx.conf and project file contains in the sites-available directory of nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the passenger_app_env was at development.  I couldn't figure out which services weren't restarted so I did a reboot of the server.  Which presented some other issues, but I'm fairly certain the problem was resolved by changing that variable to `passenger_app_env production`.  Thanks for the help!